# Why do I get occasional air spurts from plumbing that hasn't been opened in months?

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture

I replaced my hot water heater last summer (about 9 months ago) and added some new plumbing for an addition to the house. I fully understand that after having the water turned off that there will be air in the lines that needs to be blown out. I went around to each faucet, turning it on after the main water supply was restored to let the air out of each one.

On random occasions, I turn the water on and get a spurt of air that splashes water on the counter and on me. This was occurring even *before* I did the work last summer, so it's not really a new issue.

I confirmed with our local inspector that our nominal water pressure from the curb is ~55PSI, so there are no pressure adjusting fittings in my home plumbing - no PRV or booster pump.

This simply seems to happen randomly - I've washed my hands in one bathroom sink a couple of times today, and the last time I was in there, I got a spurt that splashed from the bowl onto me.

**What might be causing these random air bubbles to spurt out of my faucets?**

Is it possible that work is being done by the town and that's letting air into the system?

Comment: After 9 months I would expect all air to be out of the system, unless there is a problem.  Most cities if their pipes are broken usually give a boil water notice, till stuff is flushed out.  Do you have expansion tank/s?  Possible a problem point.

Comment: I did install an expansion tank at the same time as the new WH. However, I don't think this is the cause, as I was having this issue _prior_ to the new WH/expansion tank install. We may have had one boil order here in the 30 years we've lived here. These spurts started about 18-36 months ago. The last time the plumbing had been opened prior to this WH install was probably when I replaced the water softener 15-20 years ago...

Comment: You are sucking air in somewhere.  Most pipe leaks should only let in air when the water is turned off, and should be noticed by now.  It seems this might need eyes on it.  The only thing I can think of is low water pressure and two faucets open at the same time, and one sucks air in, but odd.

Comment: That does sound reasonable, except... we did an air-pressure test before connecting it to the existing supply lines. It held 100PSI for about an hour. PEX will expand so it dropped a little after that. Any leaks in the connections to existing supply lines would be very obvious because they'd be dripping in the root cellar basement. This is odd. And, **it happened before I did my work**. :shrug:

Comment: Any water hammer resistors/whatever?  Some fancy ones work like tiny expansions tanks with the air separated by a piston.

Comment: Nope, not a one. Never had a need, still don't. Thankfully!

Comment: No bad smell indicating the anode in the waterheater is making hydrogen sulfide, presumably, or you would have mentioned it. And that would only show up in hot. Seems like it would have to be air in the city system for some reason, then...

Comment: Nope, no smells. Brand new WH, so the anode had _better_ not be bad already!

Comment: It would be interesting to take note if the spurts are coming from the hot water or cold water to help narrow down sources. You might intentionally turn on just cold water for a time and see what happens. If it only happens with cold water, this could be dissolved air that has come out of solution when ice cold water from the main has remained in the pipe for at least a few hours and warmed up, releasing dissolved air from solution. Warm liquids can't hold as much gas in solution as cold liquids.

Comment: Would it be easy to add a tee and faucet just after where the water comes in?  That should limit if the house or city problem.

Comment: Any water pumps in the system?  Not sure but pump cavitation might add air, but should also lead to a failed pump soon.

Comment: @crip659 what would the Tee & faucet do for me? Unfortunately, it's random enough that I don't know that I could stand there long enough, turning it on/off to see if it proved anything. I did add a whole-house recirc pump that only runs upon occupancy detection in the 2 far bathrooms. The most recent spurt happened in the original, closest bath that did _not_ activate the pump. These spurts did happen prior to pump installation...

Comment: @MTA that sounds like the most plausible suggestion so far. It is winter time, and we did just get 4" of snow a couple of days ago, so everything's been extra cold. I cannot say if this has happened in relation to cold weather in the past or not, but I'll be aware of it now and try to make note of it in the future.

Comment: @FreeMan If a rarely used sink is supplied by a T, if the leg of the T points upward, and if the straight-through part of the T supplies a frequently used fixture with modest flow, any small bubble that forms before the T due to cold water reaching room temperature overnight *could* rise into the pipe that supplies the rarely used sink. Repeat 50 times and you'll have a significant volume of air that will spurt.

Comment: Ahhh. That makes sense. Except that these aren't _rarely_ used faucets. The most recent was from the original bathroom which is used a couple of times a day (often to fill the dogs' water bowl), and sometimes it happens in the kitchen sink which is used... frequently.

Comment: The anode thing would be some water chemistires need an aluminum rather than standard zinc anode or the water heater gets H2S gas due to the interaction of the chemistry and the anode material. Not a subject I have deep knowledge of, but it woudn't be "the anode is bad" it would be "the water stinks with the new water heater" - anyway, not your problem, it seems.